# drawing box diagram by Tikz with color

Tags: tikz-arrows

The code for diagram with color and arrow as below:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.8cm, start chain=going below, punktchain/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black, very thick, text width=25em, minimum height=3em, text centered, on chain},every join/.style={->, thick,shorten >=1pt}]
 \begin{scope}[nodes={join, punktchain}]
 \node (1) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
 \node (2) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
 \node (3) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
 \node (4) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
 \node (5) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
 \node (6) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
 \node (7) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
 \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

then the result does not look like the one I expected as:
[image]

Then, any suggestions for me is appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain in detail what your expectations are regarding the output of your code? Of course the output of your document looks different from the picture, as your code defines a linear chain, from top to bottom, of seven rectangles with rounded corners, black and white. And this is what the output is. So what is it that you have problems with? Arranging boxes in two dimensions, coloring them, ...?

Comment: yes, then i don't know how to make them as the expexted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MWE has little to do with your image, here is a solution with `chains` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    punktchain/.style={rectangle,draw=cyan,
        fill=cyan!30!white,
        very thick, text width=20em, minimum height=3em, text centered},
    darknode/.style={fill=cyan!70!green, draw=cyan},
    mednode/.style={minimum height=5em},
    bignode/.style={minimum height=12em},
    myarrow/.style={-{Triangle}, very thick, shorten >=1pt},
    every join/.style={myarrow},
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={punktchain}]
\begin{scope}[start chain,nodes={join, on chain}]
    \node[bignode, darknode] (A) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
    \node (B) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
    \node[bignode] (1) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=going below}]
        \node (2) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
        \node[mednode] (3) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
        \node[mednode] (4) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
        \node (5) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
        \node[mednode] (6) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
        \node[mednode] (7) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
        \node (8) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
        \node (9) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
    \end{scope}
    \node (10) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
\end{scope} 
\node[anchor=south, darknode] (C) at (A.south -| B) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
\draw[myarrow] (C.east) -- (C -| 1.west);
\node[right = of 2] (R2) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
\draw[myarrow] (2) -- (R2);
\draw[myarrow] (R2) |- (3);
\node[above=of R2, darknode] (R1) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
\draw[myarrow] (R1) -- (R2);
\node[left=of 3, darknode] (L3) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
\draw[myarrow] (L3) -- (3);
\node[left=of 4, darknode, mednode] (L4) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
\draw[myarrow] (L4) -- (4);
\node[left=of 6, darknode, mednode] (L6) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
\draw[myarrow] (L6) -- (6);
\node[left=of 7, darknode, mednode] (L7) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
\draw[myarrow] (L7) -- (7);
\node[left=of 8, mednode] (L8) {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa};
\draw[myarrow] (L8) -- (8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]